# Replace " documentation" suffix in standard HTML output in Sphinx

Tags: html, python-sphinx

The standard Sphinx HTML output (pyramid theme) creates the root link on top of all pages in the following template:

```
project + " documentation"
```

The output link looks like what we see in https://docs.python.org/3/ page. "Documentation" suffix in page title as well as top-most links.

Is it possible to remove or replace the suffix "documentation" with some other word such as "Guide" etc.?

Comment: Which theme? I don't see what you are talking about. Do you mean in the `<title>` tag?

Comment: In pyramid (also bizstyle) theme. I also see that alabaster theme just use the project name in the HTML page. Seems it is dependent on template?

Comment: Perhaps it works if you edit the `html_title` variable: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_title

Comment: `html_title` variable is the exact solution. Since it was not maintained in the default conf, it derived the defaults to '<project> v<revision> documentation' as the docs suggest in @mzjn comments.